# How to install AMD radeon graphic in ubuntu 23.04

Tags: apt, dependencies, amd-graphics, amdgpu

I could not install amd graphic card

```
hecs@TheCSPC:~$ amdgpu-install
Hit:1 https://repo.radeon.com/amdgpu/5.4.5/ubuntu jammy InRelease              
Hit:2 https://repo.radeon.com/rocm/apt/5.4.5 jammy InRelease                   
Hit:3 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/kdenlive/kdenlive-stable/ubuntu lunar InRelease
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar InRelease     
Hit:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-updates InRelease
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-backports InRelease [99.8 kB]
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-security InRelease [109 kB]
Fetched 208 kB in 4s (47.0 kB/s)  
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
linux-headers-6.2.0-20-generic is already the newest version (6.2.0-20.20).
linux-headers-6.2.0-20-generic set to manually installed.
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 amdgpu-lib32 : Depends: libdrm2-amdgpu:i386 but it is not installable
                Depends: libdrm-amdgpu-amdgpu1:i386 but it is not installable
                Depends: libllvm-amdgpu:i386 but it is not installable
                Depends: libwayland-amdgpu-client0:i386 but it is not installable or
                         libwayland-client0:i386 but it is not installable
                Depends: libwayland-amdgpu-server0:i386 but it is not installable or
                         libwayland-server0:i386 but it is not installable
                Depends: libwayland-amdgpu-egl1:i386 but it is not installable or
                         libwayland-egl1:i386 but it is not installable
                Depends: libxatracker2-amdgpu:i386 but it is not installable
                Depends: libgbm1-amdgpu:i386 but it is not installable
                Depends: libegl1-amdgpu-mesa:i386 but it is not installable
                Depends: libegl1-amdgpu-mesa-drivers:i386 but it is not installable
                Depends: libglapi-amdgpu-mesa:i386 but it is not installable
                Depends: libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-glx:i386 but it is not installable
                Depends: libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-dri:i386 but it is not installable
                Depends: mesa-amdgpu-va-drivers:i386 but it is not installable
                Depends: mesa-amdgpu-vdpau-drivers:i386 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: It doesn't look like AMD provides an installer for 23.04 or any other nonlts release. It might be better to ask someone at AMD rather than here.

Comment: I know they do not provide support for non lts, I just wanted to know if there is any way to install it in 23.04. I have moved from 22.04 to 23.04 today as I was having issues in 22.04 which all gone now but only this gpu problem

Answer (score 3):

I have been looking around this for a couple days too. They don't seem to provide support for lunar yet. However I was able to at least partially install the drivers using the jammy repository. But in your case it seems the issue you're having is that you can't find the i1386 versions of the drivers, in which case if you wouldn't need them, you can simply try by ignoring them by passing `--no-32` to exclude the i1386 versions of the drivers.

Example: `amdgpu-install --usecase=graphics -y --no-32`

Comment: E: Command line option --no-i1386 is not understood in combination with the other options

Comment: My bad, check the edit

Answer (score 2):

I have to add this for anyone wanting to get amd stack up and running on newer kernel. It solved my problems.

FYI. Where it asks you to add the 5, note that this is the version of the kernel you are using. In my case it was 6.

[AMD proprietary graphics drivers on Ubuntu 23.04](https://www.schauenburg.nl/blog/2023/07/amd_proprietary_graphics_drivers_on_ubuntu_23.04/)

Answer (score 1):

That's because the last option should be different ;-), see below:

Example: amdgpu-install --usecase=graphics -y --no-32