# low resolution and lost 2nd screen after upgrading to ubuntu 23.04

Tags: drivers, amd-graphics, 23.04

After upgrading to 23.04, 2nd screen becomes mirror to the 1st. The resolution is fixed at 1024x768~76Hz and can't changed.

amdgpu seems not having one for 23.04 yet.
Is there a way to load radeon driver?
Can I downgrade to 22.10 or 22.04LTS?

inxi shows radeon driver is not loaded.

```
$ inxi -GSC -xx
System:
  Host: Kernel: 6.2.0-24-generic arch: x86_64 bits: 64
    compiler: N/A Desktop: GNOME v: 44.2 tk: GTK v: 3.24.37
    wm: gnome-shell dm: GDM3 Distro: Ubuntu 23.04 (Lunar Lobster)
CPU:
  Info: quad core model: Intel Core i3-10100 bits: 64 type: MT MCP
    arch: Comet Lake rev: 3 cache: L1: 256 KiB L2: 1024 KiB L3: 6 MiB
  Speed (MHz): avg: 2550 high: 3600 min/max: 800/4300 cores: 1: 3600
    2: 801 3: 3600 4: 3600 5: 3600 6: 3600 7: 800 8: 801 bogomips: 57600
  Flags: avx avx2 ht lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx
Graphics:
  Device-1: AMD Curacao PRO [Radeon R7 370 / R9 270/370 OEM]
    vendor: XFX Pine Trinidad driver: N/A arch: GCN-1 pcie:
    speed: 8 GT/s lanes: 16 bus-ID: 01:00.0 chip-ID: 1002:6811
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.7 with: Xwayland v: 22.1.8
    compositor: gnome-shell driver: X: loaded: vesa
    unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,radeon dri: swrast gpu: N/A
    display-ID: :1 screens: 1
  Screen-1: 0 s-res: 1024x768 s-dpi: 96
  Monitor-1: default res: 1024x768 size: N/A
  API: OpenGL v: 4.5 Mesa 23.1.3 renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 15.0.7 256 bits) direct-render: Yes
```

try to reinstall amdgpu-install

```
amdgpu-install -y --usecase=graphics

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libegl1:i386 : Depends: libegl-mesa0:i386 but it is not installable
 libglx0:i386 : Depends: libglx-mesa0:i386 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

grep from xorg log

```
$ sudo egrep -i 'amd|radeon|\(EE\)|\(WW\)' /var/log/Xorg.0.log
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[    20.343] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[    20.343] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[    20.344] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[    20.344] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[    20.344] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[    20.418] (II) LoadModule: "radeon"
[    20.418] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/radeon_drv.so
[    20.423] (II) Module radeon: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    20.426] (II) RADEON: Driver for ATI/AMD Radeon chipsets:
    ATI Radeon Mobility X600 (M24), ATI FireMV 2400,
    ... ...
    AMD Radeon HD 6800 Series, AMD Radeon HD 6700 Series, TURKS, CAICOS,
[    20.428] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[    20.428] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
[    20.428] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[    20.429] (EE) Unable to find a valid framebuffer device
[    20.429] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[    20.429] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[    20.429] (II) UnloadModule: "radeon"
[    20.429] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[    20.429] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install AMD radeon graphic in ubuntu 23.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1469550/how-to-install-amd-radeon-graphic-in-ubuntu-23-04)

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1469550/how-to-install-amd-radeon-graphic-in-ubuntu-23-04),

1. download the latest amdgpu-install_5.6.50600-1_all.deb
2. As I wouldn't need i386 dependencies, I simply try by ignoring them by passing `--no-32` to exclude the i1386 versions of the drivers and `amdgpu-install` will rebuild initramfs for the new kernel.
   Example: `amdgpu-install --usecase=graphics -y --no-32`
   You will still see a bunch of Possible missing firmware warning, but all are good for me.
3. reboot